# aws s3 cpp sdk finning connection with minio after handshake wih tls 1.2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, minio

I'm working with a MINIO server and AWS cpp SDK client.
Everything works with HTTP, but after switching to HTTPS I'm getting "NETWORK CONNECTION" errors.
In Wireshark the connection is:

- client Hello
- server hello
- server sends Certificate , Server key exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
- client sends ack
- client sends FIN, ACK

When activating debug, aws logs the following error: WinHttpSyncHttpClient [54364] Send request failed: A certificate is required to complete client authentication

What works:

- AWS CLI to the MINIO (works with TLS 1.3 so the connection looks different)
- The same SDK with no SSL connection (when turning if off in MINIO as well).
- The same SDK works well with AWS S3 (with SSL).

What was tried and does not work:

- Turning "verifySSL" on and off
- Sending and not sending region
- Manually switching to HTTP 1.1

Does anyone have ideas on how to identify\solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We managed to bypass the problem by switching to OpenSSL instead of WinHttpSyncHttpClient, by turning the relevant flag in AWS SDK CMake file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).